# How to navigate through an array of unordered keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Hello i want to pagination an array with for loop but the problem is my array keys is not like(1,2,3,4,5 ... etc) ,,

```
   for ($x=0; $x<$members_per_page; $x++) {
        $position = (int) ($currentPage-1) * $members_per_page + $x;

        $member = get_userdata($members[$position]);
        blackfyre_clan_members_links($member,$post_meta_arr, $post_id, $isleader);

        if ( $position >= $last_key ) break;
    }
```

and my array content is :

```
         Array
         (
          [4] => Array
          (
          [boid] => 4
          [cr_nickname] =>
          )
          [564] => Array
          (
          [boid] => 564
          [cr_nickname] =>
          )
          ) .... ETC
```

Comment: Use foreach instead of for

Answer (score 0):

You could force your array to have sequential keys by using `array_values` like below:

```
for ($x=0; $x<$members_per_page; $x++) {
        $position = (int) ($currentPage-1) * $members_per_page + $x;

        $member = get_userdata(array_values($members)[$position]);
        blackfyre_clan_members_links($member,$post_meta_arr, $post_id, $isleader);

        if ( $position >= $last_key ) break;
    }
```

However a (possibly) better way to paginate would be :

```
$offset = (int) ($currentPage-1) * $members_per_page;
$slice = array_slice ($members, $offset, $members_per_page,true);
array_walk($slice, function ($member) use ($post_meta, $post_id, $isleader) { 
    blackfyre_clan_members_links($member,$post_meta_arr, $post_id, $isleader); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use foreach ($members as $member){} instead of for